# Adding attribute table into layout with PyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, layouts

According to the latest official QGIS 3.X API reference there is a [class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Layout/QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.setMap) that should insert attribute table of a layer. I tried to do it, but got an error.

Here is a piece of code I used:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName('console')
manager.addLayout(layout)
itemMap = QgsLayoutItemMap.create(layout)
tbl = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.create(layout)
layer_attr =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(u'buildings')[0]
tbl.setVectorLayer(layer_attr)
layout.addLayoutItem(tbl)
```

And after the last line I get an error

> TypeError: QgsLayout.addLayoutItem(): argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable'

Can't understand why it is happening because QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable logically should be supported by layout methods.
Main things in my code were taken from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277223/qgsprintlayout-setup-from-pyqgis-3).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at this thread: [Creating and manipulating an HTML frame in QGIS 3.2.0 Print Composer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292682/creating-and-manipulating-an-html-frame-in-qgis-3-2-0-print-composer-using-pyqgi)

I think its the same process for an attribute table. 
You have to add a QgsLayoutFrame with this commandline: `layout.addLayoutItem()`