# Displaying map title in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, osgeo4w

I have the following map but I don't know how to make a title appear on top of it. Any suggestion on how to?

[image]

Comment: Not a definite answer, but here you have an example: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#decorators

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your requirements, you may want to use a [`QgsLayoutItemLabel`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLabel.html) or a [`QgsLayoutItemHtml`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemHtml.html). To illustrate, we use `QgsLayoutItemLabel`. For `QgsLayoutItemHtml`, you may look at [this existing question and its answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292682/creating-and-manipulating-an-html-frame-in-qgis-3-2-0-print-composer-using-pyqgi)

```py
from qgis.core import QgsLayoutItemLabel, QgsLayoutPoint, QgsLayoutSize
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('demo')

new_layout_item_label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
layout.addLayoutItem(new_layout_item_label)
new_layout_item_label.setText("My title")
new_layout_item_label.setHAlign(Qt.AlignCenter)
new_layout_item_label.setVAlign(Qt.AlignVCenter)

new_layout_item_label.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(page_size.width(), 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
new_layout_item_label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(0, 0, page_size.units()))
```